# SOQL statement across Account, Contact and AccountContactRelation in SF

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to write a SOQL statement to fetch data from three objects
Account, Contact and AccountContactRelation.

I am able to get data : 1 Account with array of 1..N Contacts from this query :

```
SELECT 
Account.Name, 
Account.Id, 
(SELECT Contact.Id, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName FROM Account.Contacts), 
FROM Account 
WHERE Account.Id = 'XXXX'
```

Table AccountContactRelation has three fields that I need to include to Contact query. When I tried to embed a additional query into the existing one, I am getting an error Unknown error parsing query, the query below.

```
SELECT 
Account.Name, 
Account.Id, 
(SELECT Contact.Id, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, (SELECT AccountContactRelation.ContactId, AccountContactRelation.IsDirect FROM AccountContactRelations) FROM Account.Contacts), 
FROM Account 
WHERE Account.Id = 'XXXX'
```

When I build the query in another way I am getting the data,

```
SELECT+Account.Name,+Account.Id,+(SELECT+Contact.Id,+Contact.FirstName,+Contact.LastName+FROM+Account.Contacts),+(SELECT+AccountContactRelation.ContactId, AccountContactRelation.IsDirect, AccountContactRelation.LastModifiedDate+FROM+AccountContactRelations)+FROM+Account+WHERE+Account.Id+=+'XXXX'
```

but the result is 1 Account with array of 1..N Contacts, and second array of 1..N AccountContactRelations.

```
{
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {

            "Name": " test x",
            "Id": "vKM3QAN",
            "Contacts": {
                "totalSize": 2,
                "done": true,
                "records": [
                    {

                        "Id": "QnQAI",
                        "FirstName": "aaa",
                        "LastName": "bbb"
                    },
                    {

                        "Id": "9QAC",
                        "FirstName": "ccc",
                        "LastName": "ddd"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "AccountContactRelations": {
                "totalSize": 2,
                "done": true,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "ContactId": "QnQAI",
                        "IsDirect": true,
                        "LastModifiedDate": "2023-09-13T07:40:54"
                    },
                    {

                        "ContactId": "9QAC",
                        "IsDirect": false,
                        "LastModifiedDate": "2023-11-03T14:08:02"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to include the fields like AccountContactRelation.IsDirect and others into the first array, like below :

```
{
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {

            "Name": " test x",
            "Id": "vKM3QAN",
            "Contacts": {
                "totalSize": 2,
                "done": true,
                "records": [
                    {

                        "Id": "QnQAI",
                        "FirstName": "aaa",
                        "LastName": "bbb",
                        "IsDirect": true,
                        "LastModifiedDate": "2023-09-13T07:40:54"
                    },
                    {

                        "Id": "9QAC",
                        "FirstName": "ccc",
                        "LastName": "ddd",
                        "IsDirect": true,
                        "LastModifiedDate": "2023-11-03T14:08:02"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how to do that.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!
You have few options here, depends what you expect as end result, what format is closest to your needs.

This is pretty straightforward - you go "down" the related list once to pull relations and then "up" to the contact. You'll get a mixed bag of direct and indirect. I think that's what you're after.

```soql
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, IsDirect FROM AccountContactRelations)
FROM Account
```

This one is bit more exciting. 2 related lists, one with direct contacts, one with indirects:

```soql
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts),
    (SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName FROM AccountContactRelations WHERE IsDirect = false)
FROM Account
```

Lastly ([only via API, not available in Apex yet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm)) you could nest the related lists in the query. Something like Account -> Contacts -> their relations to other accounts. No idea if it'd be of any use to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I just modified it a bit and to get required fields. 
`SELECT+Name,+Id,(SELECT+Contact.LastName,Contact.FirstName,AccountContactRelation.ContactId,AccountContactRelation.IsDirect, AccountContactRelation.LastModifiedDate+FROM+AccountContactRelations)+FROM+Account+WHERE+Account.Id+=+'XXXX'`
Many thanks